# Elegant way to remove Media queries for Print

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have this page:
http://linkyourfuture.com/yearpage/?user=119

I am trying to get the full page w/ multiple columns to print, however, print is only recognizing the mobile CSS. How do I disable this for Print only?

I would like this to be all on 1 page when printed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your media queries within a `@media not print` query:

```
@media not print {
   @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       // stuff here
   }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xLumy01/)